# Cannot install Keras

Tags: python, keras

I am having trouble installing Keras. First I thought it was because I was using an older version of `pip`, so I upgraded:

```
$ pip install --user --upgrade pip
You are using pip version 7.1.0, however version 9.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-9.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
Successfully installed pip-9.0.3
```

Then I tried again to install Keras:

```
$ pip install --user keras
You are using pip version 7.1.0, however version 9.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Collecting keras
  Using cached Keras-2.1.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): scipy>=0.14 in /path/to/python/2.7.8/intel/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from keras)
Collecting numpy>=1.9.1 (from keras)
  Using cached numpy-1.14.2.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "/local/tmp/pip-build-VXIWgu/numpy/setup.py", line 34, in <module>
        raise RuntimeError("Python version 2.7 or >= 3.4 required.")
    RuntimeError: Python version 2.7 or >= 3.4 required.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /local/tmp/pip-build-VXIWgu/numpy
```

Interestingly, even though I successfully installed `pip` version 9.0.3, it's still using the older `pip`.

The error says I need Python version 2.7 or >= 3.4. However, I have Python 2.7:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Sep 18 2014, 11:21:42) 
[GCC Intel(R) C++ gcc 4.4 mode] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47271763/cannot-install-keras-on-conda-with-python-2-7), I thought the problem might be TensorFlow. So I checked my version:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.7.5 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:105] Couldn't open CUDA library libcudnn.so.4.0.7. LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /path/to/python/2.7.8/intel/lib:/path/to/slurm/15.08.10/lib
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:3304] Unable to load cuDNN DSO
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so.7.5 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so.7.5 locally
>>> tf.__version__
'0.10.0rc0'
```

I clearly have TensorFlow installed.

So how can I fix this? (Note: I do not have admin privileges - cannot use `sudo`).

Comment: Do you have 2 python versions installed? Did you try to update pip? Actually once pip is updated it removes the older pip versions, as far as I know, except when you are using two python versions (e.g. 2.7 and 3.x). Then you need to use pip and pip3

Comment: I did try to update pip (see the first part of the post). I only have one version of Python.

Comment: You most likely have multiple python installations, it seems you have an Intel python distribution, and also the one installed by the system. Can you describe your system installation, linux distribution, and python installations?

Answer (score 0):

If you want more control of your environment, you could create a virtual environment

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv -p=python2.7 controlledENV
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you explain why this would help? AFAIK, I still wouldn't have sudo privileges.

Comment: You don't need sudo privileges. This allows you to have a controlled environment to do pip stuff in. It looks like your environment is a little out of control. It's a little goofy because you need to have some control over `pip` to install `virtualenv`.